# Using a local SQL database in Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a Visual C# program and have added a local database through the `Add->New Item...` dialog.

The guides I have read about using this type of database then instructed to make a `data source` using the database and then in the `data sources` toolbar just drag and drop a table to create the tools for entering data into the database and reading data from it.

This isn't how I want to access the database, though.  I want to have completely different controls for the user and then just directly interface with the database in my code.  I haven't been able to find anything that explains how to do this, though. Can anybody offer any advice? Do I need to use `LINQ` for this or would it be just as good for me to use `SQL`?

Comment: I recommend against using LINQ to SQL. It is very limited when compared to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx

Comment: For anyone who is viewing this topic and wants more information, I was recently given a few more links that helped me out a lot. This one helped me with the Visual Studio databases: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce

Comment: Another user here recommended I try out SQLite, which ended up working way better for my purposes, and he gave me the following links: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/using-sqlite-with-net/

Comment: SQLite link 2: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c%23/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you must [have to learn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx) the [Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565) classes (ADO.NET). For direct access to Microsoft SQL Server use data provider classes for `MsSql` server (System.Data.SqlClient). In order to use LINQ, you must have know-how of Data Provider classes, Generics, Delegates and Anonymous methods.